# How to use __filename in angular library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I have two angular 13 projects - an application and a library. In both projects I need to use `__filename`. To do it in the application I use `"@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser"` builder with the custom webpack config:

```
export default (config: webpack.Configuration, options: CustomWebpackBrowserSchema, targetOptions: TargetOptions) => {
  config.node = {
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true
  };
  return config;
}
```

However, I can't find a solution to use `__filename` in angular library. As I understand webpack is not used in library building.

Could anyone say, how to get __filename in the library, if it is possible.

Comment: What do you need that for?